# Conditioning on random vector

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability

If I have a conditional probability distribution $\mathbb{P}(X|Y)$, with $X, Y$ being random vectors, do $X$ and $Y$ need to have the same size, i.e., dimensionality?

Comment: No, $X$ and $Y$ do not need the same dimensions

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you maybe tell me why this is the case